# Asymptotics behaviour of the sum

Tags: asymptotics

Let $S(n) = \sum_{k = n}^\infty \frac{ln^q k}{k^p}$, $p > 1$

How to determine asymptotic behaviour of the sum $S(n)$, ($n \rightarrow \infty$).

The use of integrals doesn't solve the problem.

Also I used Stolz–Cesàro theorem to solve the problem, but I can't.

What is the first step of solving?

$ S(n) $ ~ ??

Comment: It converges when p>1

Comment: Maybe I need to know sum for k from 1 to infinity and the sum for k from 1 to n. 
And next subtract one from another.

Comment: Oh sorry. I misread the index. I thought you were summing from 1..

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say integrals are of no use?
$$
\int_{n+1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^q}{x^p}\,dx\le\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{(\ln k)^q}{k^p}\le\int_{n}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^q}{x^p}\,dx.
$$
From here you get (integrating by parts)
$$
S(n)\sim\frac{(\ln n)^q}{(p-1)\,n^{p-1}}.
$$

Comment: Apparently I was afraid such an integral and stopped.